# Remove accidental .dll file association

Tags: windows, windows-10, notepad++, file-association

On Windows 10 I have accidentally set the association for .dll files to Notepad++ - how can I remove the association so that dll files go back to having no assocation?

I found this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/490421/how-to-revert-an-accidental-file-association), which concerns .exe files rather than .dll

I have poked aorund the registry, but I can't seem to find any Notepad++ entries for associations

Comment: File associations are multi-level..and there are atleast 3 places where you can set associations. This may be what you need [How to Remove a File Association Using the Registry Editor?](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/remove-file-association-windows/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this REG file to reset the association settings for `.DLL` file type.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.dll]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.dll]
@="dllfile"
"Content Type"="application/x-msdownload"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.dll\PersistentHandler]
@="{098f2470-bae0-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}"    

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.dll\UserChoice]
```

Copy the above lines to Notepad and save the file with `.REG` extension. Double-click the file to apply the settings to the registry.