# Internet Explorer runs whenever I run an exe file

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, malware

I'm using Windows 7. Whenever I try to run an `.exe` file, Internet Explorer runs with it. How can I fix this? P.S. `.exe` files are working fine, but IE runs with them automatically.

Comment: Probably you've got a malware which changed `.exe` file association. Look [here](http://superuser.com/questions/362827/how-to-repair-a-broken-exe-file-association) for solving it. And scan your computer for malware.

Comment: that's not working, i have said that my exe files working fine , it just pop up IE window when i run it.

Comment: First of all, we'd like to get more information.
1) Run cmd as admin (Start Menu-> type `cmd.exe` -> right click on it -> `Run as administrator`), write there `reg export hkcr\exefile c:\uploadme.txt`, go to C:\ and upload that file.  
2) Open Task Manager (Ctrl+Shift+Esc) `Processes` tab -> check (if not checked) `View processec of all users`  -> `View` menu -> `Select columns` -> check `Command Line`. Now a new column named `Command Line` will appear in taskmgr. Run your exe file and tell us what's written in taskmgr Command Line column behind `iexplore.exe`(or just send a screenshot).

Comment: If you're good at Windows, try [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx), find odd autorun entries and remove them, restart computer. Don't try if you're not so good at Windows. Also install a strong antivirus (even trial version, but not that free ones) and scan your computer for malware.

Comment: @Jet thanks for trying to help, here is reg export notpad u can check it [here](http://shrib.com/9pxTZhW6). also about command line it's the directory of the program. example:"E:\Folder1\Folder2\file.exe" and here is an image of IE command line > [HERE](http://prntscr.com/49q02o) - and btw i'm not good at Windows so i won't try Autoruns cuz i don't want to damage my windows(cuz i have many important files and programs hard to get them back). Thanks again for trying to help me.

Comment: I've just checked them, they seem to be OK. I will tell you a way to use Autoruns without harming the system. It usually solves such problems. [Download it](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) and run it as administrator.First of all, press `Save` button (for backup). 
Now go to these tabs: `Logon`, `Explorer`, `Internet Explorer`, `Scheduled Tasks`, `Services` and uncheck all except Microsofts (look at `Publisher` column and you'll see it) . Also leave your videocard/device items as they are (their `Publisher` will be e.g. Nvidia etc). After all reboot the system.

Comment: @Jet Thanks for trying to help, I have followed your steps and unmarked all Microsoft Corporations, but that didn't fixed my problem.
ah and btw i don't have an antivirus since i'm working on a game server files on my computer which antivirus sometimes block them.
so which antivirus do u suggest for me without affecting my server files ?

Comment: By strong antivirus I usually mean old but gold Kaspersky/Norton Internet Security and not that free-fakes. These are not free, but their trial versions will do the work. (P.S. I had AVG, Avast, Avira but they couldn't catch the same viruses, so they lost my trust)